# Powershell takes a long time to load on start-up while loading ssh-agent / git

Tags: git, powershell, ssh

I have Powershell set to use posh-git through Git for Windows. In my profile file I have this:

```
# If Posh-Git environment is defined, load it.
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
. $env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1
```

Every time I open Powershell it requests the passphrase for my id_rsa key. That's fine but it takes longer and longer to actually display the request. When I first set it up this way it prompted for the pass quite fast but the loading times increased over time.

Any suggestions? I don't even know what to begin with in looking into this.

Comment: Posh-Git startup is slow for me too. It seems we are not alone: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/82

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is indeed slow setting of user environment variables. I recently merged [a change](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/commit/bcf1a4defb341fa1e8efdfaebe594070b370a0ad) that uses a temp file instead.

The latest GH4W (1.0.48.0) includes this change.

Comment: I noticed it was loading properly after the last update without actually seeing the replies here and that you guys have nailed the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I traced this problem down to this: https://superuser.com/questions/565771/setting-user-environment-variables-is-very-slow

Since chrome have many processes that takes time to response, I simply closed down Chrome in my profile.ps1 like this.

```
$agent = Get-Process -Name ssh-agent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$chrome = Get-Process -Name chrome -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$chromepath = $null
if(!$agent -and $chrome){
    Write-Host "Chrome is open, press any key to close"
    $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() | out-null
    $chromepath = $chrome[0].Path
    $chrome | Stop-Process
}
Start-SshAgent -Quiet

if($chromepath){
     Start-Process $chromepath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (without passphrase requests). Reinstalling helped. It is the advice given [here](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/82):

> Eiter way, today I completely removed all traces of posh-git
>   (including the entries in Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) and cloned
>   it from source. This solved the problem for me!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually I wanted to avoid re-installing posh-git, these things break in a blink on windows. however I noticed in the Local>Github folder a log file. TheLog.txt was quite big by now and I decided to empty it. The prompt loads now instantly. I'm not entirely sure if this was the issue, but right now it would corroborate with your fix.

Comment: Minor update, the log file is not the issue, I still experience the slowdown, I guess I'll re-install posh.